# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a stringified JSON-Object inside another JSON-Object. I get it via `$.ajax()` from my database like this:

`data => {"foo":"[{\"foo\":\"bar\"},{\"foo2\":\"bar2\"}]"}`

When trying to do `JSON.parse(data.foo)`, I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \`.

What am I doing wrong? (Apart from the fact, that the object needs to be saved as a string.)

Comment: I did check to see if it was valid json and its good, using Jsonlint, in the event others look into that.  Could you post your code?

Comment: Could you please paste the string contained in data.foo? if you see the backslash then just JSON.parse(data.replace("\", ""))

Comment: `data =>` is not valid javascript, should be `data =`

Comment: Works for me under chrome: http://hpics.li/e0723a7

Comment: Looks ok for me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uyf4hgk25jf4wsx/2014-03-15_18-55-06.png Something wrong in outer code or server answer is not what you showed.

Comment: I also tried storing the data without the '\'. But anyway, leaving out the '\' leads to a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

Comment: Leaving '\' will cause premature end of string. Once again, data format you posted is ok.

Comment: calling data.foo in the console gives me this: "[{\"foo\":\"bar\"},{\"foo2\":\"bar2\"}]"

Comment: You sure that server answers json with ONE slash before quote? `\"`, not `\\\"`

Comment: @EdVayne if you see the \ on that string it means it has this \\\" arrangement, what happens if you do this: JSON.parse(data.foo.replace("\",""))

Comment: Here is how it going: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c33ubr4yl74b3iz/2014-03-15_19-04-29.png

Comment: Yes I'm sure about that.

Comment: What language do you use on backend?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XLpgw/

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape html tags. Which language are you using in back end? In python Django it is done by using the safe filter. Similar might exist in php or other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. It seems, the data coming from the database "looked" right, but wasn't. I assume this was because I put the data in the database by hand.
Now I put the data via my API with JSON.stringify() and now everythings looks fine.